# Script running on Linux gives NameError

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a python script running on a Linux server. The code:

```
#!/bin/python

databaseRun = input("Do you want to run all databases: ")

if databaseRun == "yes":
  print("yes")
else: 
  print("no")
```

This returns and error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./db_upg.py", line 3, in <module> databaseRun = input("Do you want to run all databases: ")
File "string", line 1, in <module> NameError: name 'yes' is not defined
```

Now if I type this code into PyCharm it runs with no problem. What am I missing? Basically you will put yes or no will be the only to answers

Answer (score 1):

You're probably running this with Python 2 instead of Python 3. Try running it with `python3 <scriptname>` instead of `python <scriptname>`. And change the shebang line from `#!/bin/python` to `#!/usr/bin/python3` respectively.

In Python 2, `input()` reads the input as a code instead of a string. Thus when you type `yes`, it reads it as a variable `yes` which is undefined. If you want to run this with Python 2 instead of Python 3 as your tag suggests, use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`. Python 2's `raw_input()` returns a string, similar to Python 3's `input()`.

Comment: when i run the script this is what i type:
./db_upgrade.py

Comment: @MIcheal In that case, just change the shebang line to `python3` like I suggested.

Comment: Sorry about that, I missed that line. 

It now gives me an error bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: so I was playing around an I got this:

`yes = 1`
`if databaseRun == 1:`

this works.

Comment: I updated it once more, try `#!/usr/bin/python3` instead of `#!/bin/python3` and if that doesn't work either, you might want to `sudo apt-get python3` on the machine. @MIcheal